# C++: Making a template operator= overload a friend

Tags: c++, templates, friend

So I have a templated vektor class

```
template<t>
class vektor
{
...
}
```

and I want to be able to write

```
vektor<int> x;
vektor<float> y;
...
y = x;
```

so I modify the class

```
template<t>
class vektor
{
    template<typename U>
    vektor<T>& operator=(const vektor<U> &r) {
    ....
    }
...
}
```

And I'd like this function to be friend with r; that is, I want to be able to access the private members of r. Since operator= is special I can't overload operator= as a non-member function and friend it as I might normally do and friend declarations of say

```
template<typename U> friend vektor<U>& operator=(const vektor<T> &r);
```

also return "must be a nonstatic member function"

Is there a way to confer friendship in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two quick solutions for this problem (both of them are not ideal).

Suppose that the class with very interesting name `vektor` looks like this (it is only an example which should illustrate the following code):

```
template<typename T>
class vektor
{
    T data;

public:

    vektor(T otherData) :
        data(otherData)
    {
    }

    T GetData() const
    {
        return data;
    }

    // ...

};
```

Both of solutions can be tested on the following example of code:

```
vektor<int> x(1);
vektor<float> y(2.0f);

y = x;
std::cout << "x.data = " <<  x.GetData() << std::endl;
std::cout << "y.data = " <<  y.GetData() << std::endl;
```

### First solution: auxiliary friend function template

In this solution an auxiliary friend function `Copy` is used to execute all copy operations and is called from copy assignment operator:

```
template<typename T>
class vektor
{
    // ...

public:

    // ...

    template<typename U>
    vektor<T>& operator=(const vektor<U>& r)
    {
        return Copy(*this, r);
    }

    template<typename V, typename U>
    friend vektor<V>& Copy(vektor<V>& l, const vektor<U>& r);

};

template<typename V, typename U>
vektor<V>& Copy(vektor<V>& l, const vektor<U>& r)
{
    l.data = static_cast<V>(r.data);

    return l;
}
```

### Second solution: friend class template

Second solution is to make all `vektor` class template instantiations friends to each other:

```
template<typename T>
class vektor
{
    // ...

public:

    // ...

    template<typename U>
    vektor<T>& operator=(const vektor<U>& r)
    {
        data = static_cast<T>(r.data);

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    friend class vektor;

};
```